# Difference between SQLiteException and SQLException in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqlexception

I am using *SQLite* *Database* in android as we do.

In my code wherever I do database operations like `rawQuery`, `execSQL` using SQLite Adapter class, I normally uses `try-catch` statements.

*For example ---*

```
try
{
    //Database Operations using rawQuery or execSQL..
}
catch(SQLiteException e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But obviously `SQLiteException` is the subclass of `SQLException`.

**NOTE:**

There are two types of *SQLException*:

`android.database.SQLException`, `java.sql.SQLException`

I am talking about the former.

So why can't we just use ---

```
    try
    {
        //Database Operations using rawQuery or execSQL..
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What is inherited or lie in between `SQLiteException` and `SQLException` that can remain uncaught if we just use `SQLiteException` that can be caught only by `SQLException`?

Answer (score 0):

**SQLException**

> An *exception* that indicates there was an error with SQL parsing or
>   execution.

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    java.lang.Throwable
       ↳    java.lang.Exception
           ↳    java.lang.RuntimeException
               ↳    android.database.SQLException
```

Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/SQLException.html

**SQLiteException**

> A *SQLite exception* that indicates there was an error with SQL parsing
>   or execution.

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    java.lang.Throwable
       ↳    java.lang.Exception
           ↳    java.lang.RuntimeException
               ↳    android.database.SQLException
                   ↳    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
```

Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteException.html

---

SQLiteException is specific sqlite error and SQLException maybe not.

Comment: What should remain "unidentified" if we only use `SQLiteException` that can only be "identified" by `SQLException` ? What is best to use when using sqlite in android ? Practically applicable example will be fine.

Comment: Correct. SQLiteException is specif SQLExceptions errors. look https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database